# Accessing Key/Value pairs using HttpListener

Tags: c#, .net, webserver, key-value, httplistener

**EDIT:** Please note that this is a WinForms application, not a web app.

I am using the `WebClient.UploadValues(Uri, "POST", NameValueCollection)` to send values to an instance of `HttpListener`. On the listener side, when the `HttpListener.GetContext()` method returns, I can access the sent data as a `byte []`.

I can convert this data to text using `EncodingXXX.GetString(buffer)` which returns the following:

- Key1=Value1
- Key2=Value2
- ...

Each item in the string is delimited by the ampersand sign `&`. Both the key and value are encoded using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode/HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` so I can split the data based on ampersands fine. The equal `=` sign, however does not get encoded if the key or value contains it.

The equal sign in the data is to be expected and since HtmlEncode does not take care of it, are there other standard utility classes that can help out? I'd like to avoid manual string replacement if possible since it is error-prone.

Comment: `The equal = sign, however does not get encoded if the key or value contains it` This means your client sends invalid data. It should have been escaped. Just ignore the request.

Comment: @EZI: Both the client and server have been written by me. That's the question. If HtmlEncode does not escape the equal sign, how can I encode it properly without resorting to custom string replacements which are error prone?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen: The other question you linked to is also my own. The example in use is the same but the questions are completely different.

Comment: @RaheelKhan okay, fair enough. But I do believe my answer to the other one should answer this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `HttpUtility.UrlEncode / HttpUtility.UrlDecode` are better suited to this kind of data.